# ReSharper Inspections: Unknown tools version 17.0

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, resharper, code-inspection

While running the TeamCity ReSharper inspection command-line tools. There is an error "unknown tools version 17.0" with the following details.

```
Inspections (ReSharper)
  Unknown tools version: 17.0
  
  --- EXCEPTION #1/1 [LoggerException]
  Message = "Unknown tools version: 17.0"
  ExceptionPath = Root
  ClassName = JetBrains.Util.LoggerException
  HResult = COR_E_APPLICATION=80131600
```

We noticed this happens after installing VS2022 or VS2022 Build Tools to build agents. Is there a way to fix it?

TeamCity Enterprise 2021.2.2 (build 99660)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to install the R# Command Line Tools (CLT) v2021.3 and enable this tool version in your build configuration.
[image]

TeamCity 2021.2.2 does not contain R# CLT 2021.3 by default.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. Turns out our support normally updates tools when they update TC but they forgot this time.